# Regression models: cases per independent variable?

Tags: regression, predictor

In logistic regression and cox regression, a general recommendation is to include a maximum of one independent variable (IV) for every 10 events in order to avoid overfitting. I have seen some studies which recommend that it might be acceptable with a lower figure than 10, but that's not the point here, so for the sake of discussion, we can assume 10 events per IV as the rule.

Does this also apply to the other independent variables? Consider a situation where we have n = 1000, and a dependent variable with 40 events. This should allow us to include 4 IVs according to the rule above. But what if one of the IVs have very few events, say only 15 or so? To clarify, perhaps we have a binary IV on whether the subject has had a non-fatal overdose or not, which is not very common in our sample. Only 15 out of 1000 individuals in the sample has had an non-fatal overdose. Intuitively, it seems to me that the requirement of 40 events should apply to the IVs as well, but I may be wrong.

So what does the expertise say? Is an IV with very few events a problem that restricts the use of that IV in this way, or are we free to use the IVs regardless of number of events, as long as we stick to 10 events of the DV per IV included?

Comment: It appears as if you may be using the word "cases" in two different senses in your question, once to refer to the number of rows of the design matrix and once to refer to the number of '1's for an indicator variable. If that's not the case, could you clarify what you do mean by "case" in your question?

Comment: I'm talking about cases in the sens of events, the number of '1's. To my understanding, the rule of 10 refers to number of events. I'm sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

On the average 15 events per *candidate* variable is a good rough rule of thumb.  This applies to both model building and to parameter estimation, hence the use of the word *candidate*.  **But** you need 96 observations just to estimate the intercept in a binary logistic model such that the margin of error in the predicted risk with 0.95 confidence does not exceed $\pm 0.1$.

A more recent paper [here](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-14-137) suggests 20:1 events:candidate variable, and a *much* higher figure when machine learning is used.

Comment: The link is broken for me.  What paper is that for the 20:1 rule of thumb?

Comment: van der Ploeg, T., Austin, P.C. & Steyerberg, E.W. (2014). Modern modelling techniques are data hungry: a simulation study for predicting dichotomous endpoints. BMC Med Res Methodol 14, 137. https://doi.org/10.1186/1471-2288-14-137

Answer (score 0):

There's a few thing's I'd try:

1. I'd try bootstrap with those n=1000 and 4 IVs. I may find that the
   regression equation is very unstable, especially for the coefficient 
   for that binary IV. If the equations are unstable, it could indicate 
   overfitting.
2. I can look at the 2x2 table between the DV and the binary IV. If for
   example, most of the 15 cases of fatal overdose had an event in the
   DV, then that IV may be crucial in predicting the DV. However, I think 
   it is unlikely to happen in usual cases and I suspect that IV is nearly
   useless.
3. I can compare the improvement in the model's ability to predict the DV 
   events by calculating the sensitivity and specificity of classifications
   with and without that IV, using the jackknife approach.

Comment: I'm talking about something like n = 100, number of events in the DV = 40 and number of '1's in one of the four IVs = 15.

Comment: Read the question now. Perhaps it's more clear.

Comment: Ok. I made changes

Comment: Thank you. You don't really answer my question, but perhaps there is no clear answer? I have a grasp on what bootstrapping is but not how to use it. And jackknife is a term I've only heard at some occasion without understanding it at all. Would you mind explaining the bootstrap and the jackknife methods briefly and how they relate to my question? I would also be happy if you could provide some R code if you work in R.

Comment: As for (2), if n = 1000, the DV has 40 events and the IV has 15 '1's, it's enough if three of the cases with a '1' on the IV has an event on the DV for the p-value to be below 0.05 (p = 0.02). In this case, I wouldn't agree that it's useless, but the chance that it will be useful in the regression model is low. How can I determine whether to keep it or not?

Comment: There's never a clear answer :) But there are tools to evaluate whether your modeling decisions make sense. Bootstrap is done by randomly selecting N observations (1000 in your case) from your data WITH REPLACEMENT and running the analysis. The you repeat that process many times, say 500 times. If the model is a good model, you will get a similar outcome 500 times. Jackknife is when you estimate the model N times, each time with one observation removed. And then you use the resulting model to classify the person who was removed. Bootstrap and jackknife both evaluate model stability.

Answer (score 0):

- `Hotaka` has the right approach I think. Bootstrapping is a great way
  of looking at the stability of model.
- This is a perhaps subtle distinction, but the 10/variable rule of thumb is meant to guide model building rather than variable estimation.
- If you have very few outcomes for a variable - the model will give you large SE/CI for the coefficient estimate for that variable. You can fit the model and the estimates are accurate, the estimates may just not be useful given the lack of data. This is different from when you try to fit too many variable to a model, where the estimates may be bias, rather than accurate but not useful.

*
- if this is of importance you could run a simulation to see if your model is reasonable. I wouldn't trust either my coding or statistical know how. But assuming only one binary predictor looking at parameter estimate. here the true value is 1.5-->

```
overfit2<-function(n){
# Parameters
      beta0 <- -3.218876
      beta1 <- 1.5

      # Initialize
      beta0hat<-rep(NA, 100000)
      beta1hat<-rep(NA, 100000)
      event<-rep(NA, 100000)
      outcome<-rep(NA, 100000)
      both<-rep(NA, 100000)
      # Simulation
      for(i in 1:100000)
      {
        #data generation
        prev<-runif(1, min=0.005, max=0.1)
        x1 <- rbinom(n=n, size=1, prob=prev)
        linpred<-beta0+x1*beta1
        pi <- exp(linpred) / (1 + exp(linpred))
        y <- rbinom(n=n, size=1, prob=pi) 
        data <- data.frame(x1=x1, y=y)
        data$both<-ifelse(x1==1 & y==1,1,0)
        #fit the logistic model
        mod <- glm(y ~ x1, family="binomial", data=data)
        #save the estimates
        beta0hat[i] <- mod$coef[1]
        beta1hat[i] <- mod$coef[2]
        event[i]<-sum(x1)
        outcome[i]<-sum(y)
        both[i]<-sum(data$both)
      }
      data.frame(x1=beta1hat, event=event, outcome=outcome, x0=beta0hat, both=both)
    }

xx<-overfit.mod(1000)
xx<-xx[which(xx$both>0),]
```

I'm just looking at parameter estimates. But you could include coverage as well.

```
p1<- ggplot(xx, aes(factor(event), x1))+geom_boxplot() 
p1+ geom_hline(yintercept=1.5)+coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,40), ylim = c(0, 4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I understand your distinction between model building and estimation.

Comment: Are you saying that few events for an IV doesn't matter, other than that the standard errors will be large? And if so, why do too few events of the DV lead to estimation bias and too few cases of an IV lead "only" to large standard errors? Shouldn't few events of an IV lead to biased estimates (for that IV) as well?

Comment: (1) Not sure I'm making sense. (2) I would use "prevalence" of the IV. I think this is what you mean. (3) this is a fair review: http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/165/6/710.full. (4) But in practical model building this is less often an issue: the confidence intervals/SE expand and fairly obvious that you shouldn't put much weight on finding. often model won't converge when you have outcomes are rare as above

Comment: (5) you might want to focus question: are you concerned about parameter estimate, model stability, or predictive ability?

Comment: Thank you. (2): I'm talking about the absolute number of '1's, regardless of number of rows in the data, so I don't mean prevalence. (3): Thanks, I've read it before (in fact, this was one of the papers I was thinking about previously) but to my understanding, it only concerns low numbers of events in the DV, not in the IV. (4): I don't have the impression that models don't converge, I have yet to encounter that and I have done quite a few regression models on a DV with few events (and thus restricted the number of IV's accordingly).

Comment: (4 continued): In any case, the IV may be strongly associated with the DV despite the low number of events in the IV so there can quite possibly be sufficiently low standard errors. I have seen this happen in some models. (5): I don't care about prediction but I care about parameter estimates of the variable(s) of interest, which may or may not be this particular IV. I'm not sure what you mean by model stability. Will you please explain?

Comment: if you are just running a main effects model - model stability refers to parameter estimates only. if you are - as is often the case - also looking at non-linearity and interactions - model stability refers to stable form of the final linear function (parameter estimates, interaction terms and non-linear terms)